# JavaFX Medusa Gauges show threshold TileKpiSkin

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use this `Gauge` from the [Medusa](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa) JavaFX library:

[image: Picure of gauge]

However when I try to build it, I get this result:

[image: Rendered Gauge]

As you can see the gauge does not display the threshold. Why is this?

This is the code I use to create the gauge:

```
public static Gauge e(String name, int value, int maxValue ) {
    Gauge gauge = new Gauge();
    //gauge.setSectionIconsVisible(false);
    gauge.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    gauge.setSkin(new TileKpiSkin(gauge));
    gauge.setMaxValue(100);
    gauge.setThreshold(60);
    gauge.setTitle("this is it");
    gauge.setValue(25);
    gauge.setValueColor(Color.WHITE);  
    gauge.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE); 
    gauge.setThresholdVisible(true);
    gauge.setThresholdColor(Color.RED);
    //gauge.setSectionIconsVisible(false);
    //gauge.setSectionsVisible(false);
    return gauge;

}
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you illustrate; this will allow others to examine your issue in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the source code for the skin you are using, the text is set to transparent which is why you see nothing in the rectangle:

```
thresholdRect = new Rectangle();

    thresholdRect.setFill(sectionsVisible ? GRAY : gauge.getThresholdColor());

    enableNode(thresholdRect, gauge.isThresholdVisible());



    thresholdText = new Text(String.format(locale, "%." + gauge.getTickLabelDecimals() + "f", gauge.getThreshold()));

    thresholdText.setFill(sectionsVisible ? Color.TRANSPARENT : gauge.getBackgroundPaint());

    enableNode(thresholdText, gauge.isThresholdVisible());
```

Comment: If i set (sectionsVisible ? Color.TRANSPARENT : gauge.getBackgroundPaint()) to more simply Color.YELLOW it still does not work